# How to broadcast messages when a certain condition is met

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a small Node.js app (basically only an app.js file).  In app.js I have a function that runs in intervals of 1 second (using setInterval()).

I also have Socket.IO running in app.js.

How can I broadcast messages from the body of function that runs in intervals? It has a condition, and I want it to broadcast messages when the condition inside it is met.

Comment: did you try this `io.sockets.emit('event',{msg:'message'});`

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your problem. What is wrong with doing something like this:

```
var f = function(num){
   if (num > 5){
       io.sockets.emit('event', 'your message');
   }
}
```